GoRouter: How to navigate back to a StatefulShellBranch after deep linking into a root page?
I'm trying to navigate back to the StatefulShellRoute after deep linking to a root page, but when I use context.pop() it pops into the / route page. Is there a better way to structure the GoRouter tree or a way for it to pop into the '/home' route? This is what the current GoRouter tree looks like:
GoRouter
├─ GoRoute('/')
    └─ GoRoute('rootPage')
└─ StatefulShellRoute
    ├─ StatefulShellBranch
    │   └─ GoRoute('/a')
    └─ StatefulShellBranch
        └─ GoRoute('/b')

So the current navigation flow is: deep linking into /rootPage and from here I want to tap the back arrow on top appbar on the RootPage to go to /a, but instead it goes to /. Is there a better way to set this up?
